# Inverse of which

Tags: r

Am I missing something obvious here? It appears the inverse function of `which` is missing from base R (googling and even a search on SO for "R inverse which" returns a myriad of unrelated links)?

Well, not that I can't write one, but just to relieve my frustration with it being missing and as an R-muscle flexing challenge: how would you go about writing one?

What we need is a function like:

```
invwhich<-function(indices, totlength)
```

that returns a logical vector of length `totlength` where each element in `indices` is `TRUE` and the rest is `FALSE`.

There's bound to be a lot of ways of accomplishing this (some of which are really low hanging fruit), so argue why your solution is 'best'. Oneliner anyone?

If it takes into account some of the other parameters of `which` (`arr.ind`??), that's obviously even better...

Comment: I'm not sure this is the inverse of `which`.  It's like saying that making a cake is the inverse of eating one.  You can't have an inverse because `which` only gives you indices of a vector and you can't know the vector length from the result.  Thus, no `invwhich` function in R.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One-liner solution:

```
invwhich <- function(indices, totlength) is.element(seq_len(totlength), indices)

invwhich(c(2,5), 10)
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: +1 for oneliner. Somewhat to my suprise, performance isn't all that good (though it only becomes noticeable for big vectors and lots of repetitions).

Comment: Rather effectively demonstrates that one-liners are not always the "best" solution.

Comment: `is.element` is identical to `%in%` so alternative is `seq_len(totlength) %in% indices`.

Answer (score 5):

My own solution (for now): **EDIT** as per @Marek's suggestion.

```
invwhich<-function(indices, outlength, useNames = TRUE)
{
    rv<-logical(outlength)
    #rv<-rep(FALSE, outlength) #see Marek's comment
    if(length(indices) > 0)
    {
        rv[indices]<-TRUE
        if(useNames) names(rv)[indices]<-names(indices)
    }
    return(rv)
}
```

It performs very well (apparently better than @Andrie's oneliner) and, in as much as possible, accounts for useNames. But is it possible to make this into a oneliner?

wrt performance, I simply use:

```
someindices<-sample(1000000, 500000, replace=FALSE)
system.time(replicate(100, tmp<-invwhich(someindices, 1000000)))
```

as a very lo-fi performance measurement.

Comment: You could speed it up 5x by replacing `rep(FALSE, outlength)` to `logical(outlength)`.

Comment: Or replace `rep` by `rep.int`.

Comment: This would be the oneliner: `invwhich <- function(i,len) '[<-'(logical(len),i,T)`. Or with useNames (but who's going to need that ?) : `invwhich <- function(i,len, useNames = TRUE) setNames('[<-'(logical(len),i,T),if(useNames) names(i) else NULL)`

Answer (score 1):

Another variant, to make a oneliner:

```
lWhich <- function(indices, totlength, vec = vector(length = totlength)){vec[indices] <- TRUE; return(vec)}
```

I'd prefer different names, for brevity:

```
lWhich <- function(ix, len, vec = vector(length = len)){vec[ix] <- TRUE; return(vec)}
```

Or, using the `bit` package:

```
lWhichBit <- function(ix, len){return(as.logical(bitwhich(len, x = ix, poslength = length(ix))))}
```

Surprisingly, that seems slow.  It turns out that the code uses `rep` in some places.  :(

This is a job for Rcpp or `compile`!  :)

Comment: Using ";" equates not having a oneliner... Still, I'll refund you a +1 for the effort (and if I have the time, I'll do some profiling and let you know how it went)

Comment: Ah yes, that is true; no flies on you.  :)   It was late, what can I say... I tried doing an assignment inside the return, but it got messy.

Answer (score 0):

Overkill version working with all kinds of indices:

```
#' Logical which
#' 
#' Inverse of \link[base]{which}.
#' Converts an array of any indices to a logical index array.
#' 
#' Either \code{nms} or \code{len} has to be specified.
#' 
#' @param idx       Numeric or character indices.
#' @param nms       Array of names or a sequence.
#'                  Required if \code{idx} is a character array
#' @param len       Length of output array.
#'                  Alternative to \code{nms} if \code{idx} is numeric
#' @param useNames  Use the names of nms or idx
#' 
#' @examples
#' all(lWhich(2, len = 3) == c(F, T, F))
#' all(lWhich(c('a', 'c'), letters[1:3]) == c(T, F, T))
#' 
#' @export
lWhich <- function(idx, nms = seq_len(len), len = length(nms), useNames = TRUE) {
    rv <- logical(len)
    if (is.character(nms)) # we need names here so that rv[idx] works
        names(rv) <- nms

    if (useNames && !is.null(names(idx)))
        names(rv)[idx] <- names(idx)

    rv[idx] <- TRUE

    if (!useNames) # if we don’t want names, we’ll remove them again
        names(rv) <- NULL
    rv
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setdiff(1:total_length, indices)
```

Comment: That isn't the meaning of "inverse" used here. The question is about going from a vector of numbers to a vector of true/false values, ie, what `which` does but in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `which()` but match the condition to `FALSE`:

```
# which set indices are missing in the subset 
which(FALSE == (subset %in% set))
```